# How to Get A Google Result Using PHP

Tags: php, curl

Just to clarify my goal. I type "Who directed Terminator 2?" into google and at the top of the page there is a box that says James Cameron etc. I want this information.

I have checked the code and `<div class="_eF">James Cameron</div>` is the div i want. I can grab this with a CURL request and just pick out this div, but it's quite slow. If i want to run multiple CURL requests it can cause relatively long wait times.

Surely there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

I have tried looking for google search API stuff and all i seem to find is the custom search engine that you can place on your web page. I need to be able to get this information into my php script while its running.

Comment: That format will not work the same for all questions. For example https://www.google.com/#q=what+directed+testing123

Comment: When Google changes its User Interface, your code will fail. I wonder if you read the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) carefully.

Comment: ... And Google will quickly ban you. They don't like people scrapping their pages.

Comment: THis is why im looking for a better solution. I can deal with some failed requests for now when using obscure searches, but i was hoping a cleaner and faster way of doing this. IE. an API

Comment: Google Custom Search API is your key.

Comment: What do you need it for? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and search in each div of the page... you can get the html of page with `file_get_contents()` , but i don't know if google approves it.

Comment: No. As said in comment, when any HTML changes, the code will fail.